# ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed

Tags: bluetooth, compiling, raspberrypi

I followed this link, 
https://github.com/peyo-hd/device_brcm_rpi3

I have used `make -j4` command and I get the below error :

```
1 warning generated.
[ 36% 11636/31519] Ensure Jack server is installed and started
Jack server already installed in "/home/prayasm/.jack-server"
Server is already running
[ 36% 11650/31519] build out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v8_intermediates/classes.jack
FAILED: /bin/bash -c "(mkdir -p out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v8_intermediates/classes.jack.tmpjill.res ) && (unzip -qo prebuilts/sdk/8/android.jar -d out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v8_intermediates/classes.jack.tmpjill.res ) && (find out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v8_intermediates/classes.jack.tmpjill.res -iname \"*.class\" -delete ) && (JACK_VERSION=3.26.ALPHA out/host/linux-x86/bin/jack @build/core/jack-default.args --verbose error  -D jack.import.resource.policy=keep-first -D jack.import.type.policy=keep-first -D jack.android.min-api-level=1 --import prebuilts/sdk/8/android.jar --import-resource out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v8_intermediates/classes.jack.tmpjill.res --output-jack out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v8_intermediates/classes.jack ) && (rm -rf out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v8_intermediates/classes.jack.tmpjill.res )"
Internal unknown error (500), try 'jack-diagnose' or see Jack server log
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
make: * [ninja_wrapper] Error 1
```

Is this some known issue ?

Answer (score -1):

You Can disable jack by following [disabling-jack-in-android-compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36680397/disabling-jack-in-android-compilation)

The path of of `javac.mk` is  `build/core/combo/javac.mk`

```
- ANDROID_COMPILE_WITH_JACK := true
+ ANDROID_COMPILE_WITH_JACK := false
```